# reading data from a file after skiping the header

Tags: c, file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read numbers from a file, but first i gotta skip a header, this is a small code that only serves the purpose of testing the function, now...the function to skip part of the file works fine but when i try and read somthing from the file after i get a seg fault and the error code that means Status_acces_violation, but i just can't seem to find my mistake
The info in the file is always gonne be like this
Ex:

P5

256 789

125

125 236 789 ...(a bunch of numbers)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *salt_header(FILE *poza){

   char gunoi1[2];
   fscanf(poza, "%s", gunoi1);
   printf("%s\n", gunoi1);

   int gunoi2;
   fscanf(poza, "%d ", &gunoi2);
   printf("%d ", gunoi2);

   fscanf(poza, "%d", &gunoi2);
   printf("%d\n", gunoi2);

   fscanf(poza, "%d", &gunoi2);
   printf("%d\n", gunoi2);

   return poza;
}

int main()
{    
   FILE *poza;
   char gunoi1[2], *nume;
   nume = malloc(256 * sizeof(char *));
   if(nume == NULL)
      exit(-11);

   scanf("%s", nume);
   poza = fopen(nume, "r");

   if(poza == NULL){
      printf("Failed to open file\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   poza = salt_header(poza);

   int numar;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      fscanf(poza, "%d", &numar);
      printf("%d ", numar);
   }

   fclose(poza);
   free(nume);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A 2 byte buffer to load the first "string" is pretty small... Without seeing the sample input file, it's a reasonable guess that the very first `fscanf( "%s", ...)` is writing out of bounds... Edit the question to show the input file contents. Also, you are `malloc`ing 256 pointers, not chars... That's a bit of a waste being excessive...

Comment: The input that goes into the first buffer is always gonna be one letter followed by one digit

Comment: Without seeing the input, a person can only guess. Publish or work it out for yourself, please. Is that "one letter followed by one space followed by one digit???"

Comment: Bingo! "P5" is a string of length 2 and `fscanf()` will add a '\0'... Easy, no? Now, go read the manual an figure out how to read one character into the buffer, not a contiguous series of non-whitespace characters...

Comment: I just edited the question, i'm kind of new to the platform and not really used to asking questions so thanks for the feedback

Comment: thankssss a looot:)))), i now it's a stupid mistake, but you made my night(it's 3AM where i live), thanks a lot again:))))

Comment: Dealing with unseen input burdens those who would help with _guessing_ what may be causing problems. You should have noticed that the first "print debug" was showing you it had loaded a 2 character string (plus '\0') into a 2 byte buffer... Things one learns with experience... Hope you are on your way forward, now...

Answer (score 0):

char gunoi1[5];  // "P5" : 2 bytes , "\n" : 1 byte , "\0" : byte

Comment: Close... `fscanf()` won't put '\n' in the buffer, though...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> just can't seem to find my mistake

In `*scanf()`, do not use `"%s"` without a width.

`fscanf(poza, "%s", gunoi1);` overflows `char gunoi1[2];` as it is too small to store *string* `"P5"` leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Remember a *string* always has a trailing *null character*, else it is not a string.

Also always check the return value of input functions.

---

A simple alternative, if the first line length is sane:

```
char buf[1000];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, poza)) {
  ; // Successfully read the first line.
}
```